# sorting tuples in list, using lambda function

Tags: python, sorting

What I am trying to do is sort a list of tuples, that the first cell in the tuple can be many nested tuples, but the second cell is always a int value,

My code:

```
t = [('d',2), ('b', 1), (('a', 'c'), 2)]
sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

But this is not working, the last nested tuple stays in the end.
any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue; I get `[('d', 2), (('a', 'c'), 2), ('b', 1)]`. Or did you expect `(('a', 'c'), 2)` to be sorted first?

Comment: What order do you want those three items to end up in?

Comment: i am getting ('d', 2), ('b',1).....

Comment: And note that `sorted()` **returns** a new, sorted list. If you wanted `t` to be sorted in-place, call `t.sort()` instead.

Comment: that was the issue, sort and not sorted(), i didn't understand why the list wont change!

Answer (score 4):

The sorted method return a new sorted list. It does not modify the existing list. On the other hand, list.sort() method sort the list in-place.

```
t = [('d',2), ('b', 1), (('a', 'c'), 2)]
```

To sort this use either

```
t = sorted(t, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

or

```
t.sort(t, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```